# Struct in NXC and F#

Tags: c++, c, struct, f#, nxc

I have a question:

There is such a struct function in NXC:

```
struct colorType
{
  int colorval;
  unsigned int rawRed;
  unsigned int rawGreen;
  unsigned int rawBlue;
  unsigned int normRed;
  unsigned int normGreen;
  unsigned int normBlue;
};

colorType cubeColor[6*9];
```

I have created the same struct in F# like this:

```
type colorType =
    struct 
        val colorval: int
        val rawRed: uint16
        val rawGreen: uint16
        val rawBlue: uint16 
        val normRed: uint16
        val normGreen: uint16
        val normBlue: uint16
    end
```

But I don't have any idea how to call **colorType cubeColor[6*9];** in F#.

Could you help me for this case?

Thanks.

Comment: You want to create a zeroed array of structs?

Comment: Actually the point is, I'm trying to write an NXC code again in F#. But I couldn't understand the point of struct in NXC. When writing colorType cubeColor[6*9], which values in struct are called.

Comment: @yeniden - this is just a zeroed array of structs, as Daniel has stated

Comment: So what can I do right now? Do you have an idea?

Comment: You mean like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee340488(v=vs.100).aspx ?

Comment: How can I implement this to my solution?

Answer (score 5):

As people said in the comments, *technically*, the answer is `Array.zeroCreate (6*9)`, optionally followed by `: colorType []` if the compiler cannot infer the type from context. *This creates 54 instances of the structure, sequentially placed into an array.*

However, you should be aware that:

- The meaning of `struct` in the CLI (and thus F#) is very different from its meaning in C. I don't know NXC, but you should check [the MSDN on structs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233233.aspx) to make sure this is what you want. In F#, `struct` signifies a *value type*, which is usually a performance optimization, but also alters semantics.
- In F#, values are immutable by default, and `colorType` has no constructor, so all the values will remain zeroed and you will not be able to do anything useful with it until you add a constructor. *Making the fields mutable instead will probably cause you headaches if the type remains a struct, because of the aforementioned changes in semantics. I would not recommend that.*
- While starting with a zeroed, mutable array is typical in many programming languages, it is only a sparsely used performance tool in F#. Usually, one would first start with [an immutable list with actual data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233224.aspx) or [other kinds of sequences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233209.aspx) and do mappings from the original data to new objects holding the desired result.

I would recommend to first do some tutorials or reading on F#, and get used to the language's typical tools. Topics like structs, explicit fields (val), and F#'s imperative tools might not be the best starting point.

There are many online resources for learning F#, for example [tryfsharp.org](http://tryfsharp.org/), which even features a compiler for the samples if your browser is compatible.